# AppleScript - How can I get this string to properly go through?

Tags: string, active-directory, applescript

```
set UserName to do shell script "whoami"
set AD to do shell script ("dscl "/Active Directory/YC/All Domains/" read /Users/" & UserName)
```

My error: Expected “,” but found identifier

So Im trying to find a users SMBHome in active directory because we map our drives based on that. But the issue with that command is the double strings. "/Active Directory/YC/All Domains/" HAS to a string otherwise it wont properly queue.

But to do shell script ("COMMAND HERE") has to be a string as well..

How do I combat this?

And is there a easier way todo this?

Full script:

```
set UserName to do shell script "whoami"
set AD to do shell script ("dscl "/Active Directory/YC/All Domains/" read /Users/" & UserName)

if AD contains "StaffShare" then
    set SMBHome to "smb://domain/StaffShare"
else
    set SMBHome to "smb://domain/EmployeeShare"
end if

set mounted_disk to list disk

mount volume SMBHome as user name UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I actually figured it out. Similar to Lua
"dscl \"/Active Directory/YC/All Domains/\" read /Users/" & UserName

Although Im still up to see if anyone has any better solutions for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes:

```
set AD to do shell script "dscl '/Active Directory/YC/All Domains/' read $HOME"
```

But the way you've done it, by escaping the double quotes, it perfectly legit.